# How to create selected checkbox list item using Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

How to create a list contains check-boxes using `tkinter` like in the below picture

[image]

as I need also to put column dataframe values in this list and here's my code

```
mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'
mySiteCode = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'Governance_Tracker - Copy - Copy.xlsm', usecols=['SiteCode'],
                                encoding='latin-1', header=1)

a = mySiteCode['SiteCode'].values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CheckboxTreeview` from the [ttkwidgets](https://github.com/RedFantom/ttkwidgets/) module:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from ttkwidgets import CheckboxTreeview

root = tk.Tk()
ct = CheckboxTreeview(root, show='tree') # hide tree headings
ct.pack()

style = ttk.Style(root)
# remove the indicator in the treeview 
style.layout('Checkbox.Treeview.Item', 
             [('Treeitem.padding',
               {'sticky': 'nswe',
                'children': [('Treeitem.image', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''}),
                             ('Treeitem.focus', {'side': 'left', 'sticky': '',
                                                 'children': [('Treeitem.text', 
                                                               {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})]})]})])
# make it look more like a listbox                                                               
style.configure('Checkbox.Treeview', borderwidth=1, relief='sunken')

# get data
mydir = (os.getcwd()).replace('\\', '/') + '/'
mySiteCode = pd.read_excel(r'' + mydir + 'Governance_Tracker - Copy - Copy.xlsm', usecols=['SiteCode'],
                            encoding='latin-1', header=1)

a = mySiteCode['SiteCode'].values.tolist()

# add items in treeview
for value in a: 
    ct.insert('', 'end', text=value)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer , So now If I want to put my `data-frame` values in this list like I showed above I tried to put instead `text='Item %i' % i` I put `text=a`  but it's doesn't work fine

Comment: @DevyToly I have edited my answer to include your data_frame values (`a` is a list, so you want to put the values contained in `a` in the treeview, not the `a` itself)

Answer (score 1):

From what I can gather from the documentation Tkinter does not support anything but normal textvalues in Listboxes. See: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm